# Change directory in terminal using hyperlinks

Tags: bash, hyperlink, gnome-terminal

Opening a gnome-terminal in the specified directory is straightforward:

```
gnome-terminal --working-directory ~/dotfiles
```

Creating hyperlinks is not a problem:

```
echo -e '\e]8;;file:///home/pmn/dotfiles\aThis is a link\e]8;;\a'
```

this produces a link that opens the file explorer in the correct folder when `Ctrl+Click`ed.

What I want to do is combine the two things, so that when I `Ctrl+Click` the link, a terminal pops up, already in the requested folder. It would not be a problem if the *current* terminal I'm in changed directory, but in that case I'd like to still see the previous terminal output and just do the equivalent of a regular `cd` (*Edit*: Note that the `~/dotfiles` folder is just an example, I have several links that are generated by a script, and I'd like to be able to click on them to quickly open a terminal where needed).

I tried fiddling with registering custom applications:

In `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` add:

(Note that the use of this file is deprecated, `~/.config/mimeapps.list` should be used, if you have tips on doing that properly I'm open to them)

```
[Default Applications]
x-scheme-handler/mygnometerm=mygnometerm.desktop
```

In `~/.local/share/applications/mygnometerm.desktop` add:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Name=My Gnome Terminal
Exec=/bin/gnome-terminal --working-directory=%f
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/mygnometerm
```

Create the folder for the mime database:

```sh
mkdir -p ~/.local/share/mime/packages
```

Update the mime database:

```sh
update-mime-database ~/.local/share/mime
```

This **does** work: if I right-click on a folder in the file explorer and select `My Gnome Terminal` as the app to use, a terminal is opened already in the right folder.

If I print

```sh
echo -e '\e]8;;mygnometerm:///home/pmn/dotfiles\aThis is a link\e]8;;\a'
```

and click on the link, a terminal *does* pop up, but in the root folder, and the same happens when running

```sh
gio open mygnometerm:///home/pmn/dotfiles
```

I just need to *combine* everything, but I tried a lot of combination of what to `echo` in the link and could not find the right one.

I'm also open to other ways to achieve this behaviour, but at this point I'm quite curious in how to to it this way.

The use case, for the curious, is that I made a simple script to check the status of my repos, and I want to click on the ones with things to do without having to copy and paste the path. I reckon I'll save at least 5 seconds!

Cheers!

Comment: Instead of working with these links, couldn't you just make a small clickable shell script that pops up your terminal?

Comment: @Evert How would I tell the script the destination folder? Maybe it's not clear in the question, the `dotfiles` directory is just an example: the links are generated by a shell scripts and there are several of them, and I want to be able to click on one and open a terminal in the selected folder.

Comment: If you are considering a 'hyperlink' for each folder you are interested in, you can also create a shell-script for each case, no?

Comment: Yes but there are two problems with that: 1) I'd need to manually create every link, and every time I clone a new repo I'd need to add one, while the script dynamically checks every subfolder in the folders I specify 2) the script to check the repos' state is in a terminal, opening a folder filled with links is slower than just cd'ing somewhere at that point. I'm not claiming that it will save me anything more than 5 seconds, I'm mostly curious in what I'm missing to make it work.